# how to write tests for a function using py3.5 os.scandir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-mock, python-os

How to write tests to a function using the newly added to build-ins of python 3.5 `os.scandir()`?
Is there a helper to mock a `DirEntry` objects?

Any suggestions on how to mock `os.scandir()` of an empty folder and a folder with few 2 files for example?

Comment: I think you are looking for [mock.patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) decorator

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, my solution involves `@mock.patch()` decorator.
My test became something like:

```
from django.test import TestCase, mock
from my_app.scan_files import my_method_that_return_count_of_files

mock_one_file = mock.MagicMock(return_value = ['one_file', ])

class MyMethodThatReturnCountOfFilesfilesTestCase(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('os.scandir', mock_one_file)
    def test_get_one(self):
        """ Test it receives 1 (one) file """
        files_count = my_method_that_return_count_of_files('/anything/')
        self.assertEqual(files_count, 1)
```